# PHP short sentence of stating new vairable

Tags: php, variables

I wonder if there is any way can short sentence to state a variable.

**Purpose: only for if you are in a situation have to state 20 variables at the time. more convenience**

```
$a = 1; $b = 2;

//Imagination like below

$a, $b = 1, 2;

$a = 1, $b = 2;
```

Thank you very much for your advice of alternatives.

**(If you do not have any ideas, please do not accuse the way of why have to think about this)**, because **arrray**, **(object)** are alternatives, but not match what I need on my question

Comment: what's wrong with `$a = 1; $b = 2;`? what's the point in replacing `;` with `,`? why to look for "short ways" at all? the code intended not only for writing but also for reading. And it's critical part when you're looking for some error. Why make code complicated to save of 1 or 2 symbols?

Comment: may be it is `array` you're looking for? What is the use of these variables?

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get to that syntax is using [`list()`](https://www.php.net/list):

```
<?php
    list ($a, $b) = array(1, 2);

    echo $a . ' ' . $b; // prints "1 2"
```

Its magic!

EDIT:

For even more magic, you can use [short array notation](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortsyntaxforarrays) from PHP 5.4 onwards:

```
<?php
    list($a, $b) = [1, 2];

    print $a . ', ' . $b;    // prints 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

How is `$a = 1, $b = 2;` shorter than `$a = 1; $b = 2;` ?

If for any reason you need two assignments in one statement, you could to it with `list`:

```
list($a,$b) = array(1,2);
```

However, shortening is not a valid reason for this.